# Jenkins FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: java, jenkins, jnlp, master-slave

I am getting the following error when running a shell script on Jenkins slave which in turn calls another Jython script.

```
FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:41)
    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:174)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:714)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:167)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.join(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:925)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:360)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:94)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:63)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:781)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:562)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:299)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:774)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:69)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:77
```

Here is a outline of the flow

Master (AWS) --http--> Slave (jump box behind firewall) --> SSH into another box --> Execute shell script --> Execute Jython

The last two bits [Execute shell script --> Executes Jython] is a Oracle proprietary shell script will calls Jython to deploy code. When Jython script is called with a specific option for remote deployment I get the above mentioned error. For all other options the Jython script gives the desired result and works like a charm.

When the same shell script is called from a different master which is within our network the same Jython script works without any problems. The flow is something like this

Master (Local) --> SSH into another box --> Execute shell script --> Execute Jython

To sum it up, remote deployments using proprietary Oracle Jython scripts work fine when no slave JVM is involved.

What could possibly be wrong which makes the slave JVM terminate the connection to master on AWS for remote deployments?

I have played around and its got nothing to do with timeout. The slave is not offline.

As you would have probably guessed by now, we are trying to move our Jenkins Master to AWS.

Comment: What is the connection with JWS/JNLP?

Comment: Did not understand the question Andrew. You after the connection command used? Yes it is a headless jnlp connection.

Comment: The JNLP tag stands for Java Network Launch Protocol.  What do **you** mean when you type JNLP?

Comment: How long does it take for the job to fail like this? 20 minutes?  In that case maybe it's a timeout and something is closing the connection...